# Authorization for actions (not models!) with roles in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization

If I've got a simple rails user model that has an array of roles, is it sufficient enough to control access to actions by simply checking the model's role attribute for that role and blocking/proceeding accordingly?

Is there an advanced system that I ought to leverage due to unforeseen complexity?

**Important:** I'm not looking to authorize users/roles to models (I am already aware of CanCan).  I'm looking to do security at the controller level so that I can break out the functionality in finer detail.

**Even more important:** Seriously, I'm not necessarily asking about CanCan, please read the question carefully and pay attention! :)

Comment: Maybe you are unclear how to leverage CanCan's `Ability` model to work with your roles, but from the sound of what you're asking, CanCan does exactly what you're looking for. Maybe I'm misunderstanding; your question is presented pretty abstractly.

Comment: in your action: authorize! :show, @project

Comment: You guys misunderstand.  I don't want to do authorization based on models.  I made that pretty clear in the question!

Comment: You can override the behaviour of cancan completely. Checkout: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks last chapter (Overriding All Behavior).

Comment: Does it even merit being used? I'm more asking if I even need CanCan in the first place.  (Future readers should really try to get past this!)

Comment: Question 1: YES, Question 2: NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: YES, Question 2: NO.

I just keep this simple

If you check the models attribute in the controller, the controller will restrict all users that do not have this attribute set.

ex:

```
def create
  @user.find(params[:user_id]) 
  if @user.admin?
  @post.new(params[:post]) 
  @post.create!
  end
end
```

make a method in the user model

```
def admin?
  role == "Admin"
end
```

You should make better code than this. To much logic in the controller, but this will keep all, except admins out.